# Return Features in a boundingBox QGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, migration

I am migrating a plugin from QGIS 2 to QGIS 3. The following code is QGIS 2:

```
    # Define a mapscale-dependent rectangle about the pick point.
    pntGeom = QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point)
    pntBuf = pntGeom.buffer(canvas.mapUnitsPerPixel()*4, 0)
    rect = pntBuf.boundingBox()    

    # Convert the rectangle coordinates to the layer CRS.
    layerRect = canvas.mapRenderer().mapToLayerCoordinates(layer, rect)

    # Select the features that are in the rectangle and return their fids.
    layer.removeSelection()
    layer.select(layerRect, True)
    fids= layer.selectedFeaturesIds()
```

where `canvas` is a `self.iface.mapCanvas()` object and `layer` is a `QgsVectorLayer` object.

I need this to work in QGIS 3.  The `mapRenderer()` object is obsolete and it appears the `mapToLayerCoordinates()` function is a member of the `QgsMapSettings` and requires that the `layer` argument "must have type `QgsMapSettings`" so my replacement code:

```
    layerRect = QgsMapSettings.mapToLayerCoordinates(layer, rect)
```

fails with

> TypeError: QgsMapSettings.mapToLayerCoordinates(): arguments did not
> match any overloaded call:
>
> overload 1: first argument of unbound method must have type 'QgsMapSettings'
>
> overload 2: first argument of unbound method must have type 'QgsMapSettings'

The ultimate goal is to return any feature ids that are within the bounding box.

How do I resolve this conflict?

Comment: If you've got a bounding box, why not using `layer.getFeatures(my_bbox)`? If you still need to select the features, you also have `layer.selectByRect(my_bbox)`. After that you already know how to get selected feature ids. In summary, there is no need to deal with the canvas or mapSettings.

Comment: Adding the `layer.selectByRect(my_bbox)` _rect_-ified the issue. Thanks. You may post as an answer if you wish.

Comment: Good! Added the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've got a bounding box, you can use `layer.getFeatures(my_bbox)`.

If you still need to select the features, you also have `layer.selectByRect(my_bbox)`. After that, you already know how to get selected feature ids.

In summary, there is no need to deal with the canvas or mapSettings.